# angular material dialog with ui-grid. Header height issues

Tags: angular-material, angular-ui-grid

I am using the ui-grid inside of an md-dialog.

When the grid populates, the header is larger then normal.

Has anyone successfully used ui-grid inside of md-dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Im using ui-grid inside md-dialog, I populate the ui-grid with the result from a promise.

I set the header height to a fix value `height: 50px;`.

The rest of the css just helps to wrap the text in case is longer than the column width.

I have the following css for the header.

```
.ui-grid-header-cell {
 height: 50px;
 white-space: normal;
 -ms-text-overflow: clip;
 -o-text-overflow: clip;
 text-overflow: clip;
 overflow: visible;
```

}